# Vuejs : How to trigger an event on keyup in Vue-multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, methods, vue-multiselect

**Requirement**: I have searchable dropdown, initially I will not have any dropdown items, but once a user enters a letter I wish to call an API that will give me a list of dropdown items starting with that letter (eg Typing "A" should return "apple", "ant" etc).

**In short**: I need an input field with dropdown (similar to Google's search).

I found an npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-multiselect

This is working fine when given already initialized dropdown items.

```html
<multiselect
  v-model="valueabc"
  :options="websites"
  label="url"
  track-by="url"
  class="header-select mr-3"></multiselect>
```

I want to populate options with the result of values populated from API result, but I couldn't find an event to be trigerred on keyup.

Tried: `v-on:keyup.enter="eventname"` and `@keydown="eventname"`:

```html
<multiselect ... v-on:keyup.enter="eventname"></multiselect>

<multiselect ... @keydown="eventname"></multiselect>
```

I'm afraid this cannot be achieved using this package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vue-multiselect` does have an ability to populate items asynchronously (for ajax loading, for example), no need to reinvent the wheel. Read the doc [here](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-asynchronous-select).

In short, you do it like this:

```html
<multiselect
  v-model="valueabc"
  :options="websites"
  label="url"
  track-by="url"
  class="header-select mr-3"
  :searchable="true"
  :internal-search="false"
  :loading="isLoading"
  :clear-on-select="false"
  :show-no-results="false"
  @search-change="searchWebsites"
/>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      websites: [],
      isLoading: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async searchWebsites(query) {
      this.isLoading = true;
      // make API request to load websites
      this.websites = await loadWebsites(query);
      this.isLoading = false;
    },
  },
};
```

You should adapt this example to suit your needs though.